# group_concat mysql subquery only returns one item

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, scoreTable and users. I am trying to group by hash on scoreTable but selecting all the user names that have that hash. scoreTable only has the ids

```
SELECT st.score,
GROUP_CONCAT(st.uid) as userList
FROM scoreTable st
GROUP BY hash
```

For the above query I get the list of user Ids in userList: `'1,2,3,4'`

What I would love to get is the actual "names" instead of the ids - the names are on another table (users)

```
SELECT st.score,
(SELECT group_concat(d.name) from users d d where d.uid = st.uid))
FROM scoreTable st
GROUP BY hash
```

But for some reason this only displays ONE user (the user with the first id).

Comment: Put the GROUP BY in your subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join on the `users` table:

```
SELECT   st.score, group_concat(d.name)
FROM     scoreTable st
JOIN     users d ON d.uid = st.uid
GROUP BY hash
```

Comment: @Cez The first query in the OP assumes this, I just carried on with this assumption

Comment: worked great thanks, now to figure out how to group_concat the name and id in a json format that won't break if name has double quotes...